# Error given out while trying to use the command suggested to upgrade pip in command prompt, python 3.5.2

Tags: python, pip, python-3.5

[image: "]
This is the error that is given when i use the command "python -m pip install --upgrade pip" in cmd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because your pip is installed too "deep" on your hard drive, so the path is too long. The solution is to install pip closer to the root of your hard drive.